# Lost my house. Can I teleport to quartz pillars via cheats?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Well, I just did the noobiest thing a person could do in Minecraft. Lose their house. Ok well it wasn't a house. It was the spawn for my adventure map. I really don't want to have to rebuild it. It took **forever!**

The way that I could get back is if I could teleport myself to quartz pillar blocks. This was something I used in only my spawn and nowhere else.

I forgot to mention. My "spawn" isn't actually my spawn. It was the building I made for the spawn but then I forgot to set the spawn.

Does anyone know how to teleport players to certain blocks?

I just thought of something. There is a base finder feature on the Wurst hacked client. I don't hack on servers but I find it has some useful features. Hopefully it works. I will let you know.

Comment: I take it you didn't sleep in a bed there? That is what you ment by "didn't set spawn"?

Comment: No, It's an adventure map so I was only in creative. I opened this world in MCedit, does that help me any? What I mean by didn't set spawn is that I didn't do the /setworldspawn command where I was supposed to spawn.

Comment: using McEdit you can change the view to "ChunkView" and , from the original spawn follow the already generated chunks - that represent the path you used previously -, and you'll end up finding your building.

Answer (score 3):

Due to the way blocks work in Minecraft (being singletons rather than separate instances like entities), there's no easy way to do this. Do you know approximately the coordinates? Because the more you can narrow down the search area, the easier it'll be to find.

Answer (score 3):

You can use external editors like mcedit to find out where you went and you will find the coords of your home fast. You can go to the map in mcedit by pressing tab. The the explored chunks load. Take the coordinates of your home and tp in minecraft

Comment: There are some similar tools too that I cant remeber the name of that will display a map of the areas youve explored

Comment: Could you explain how to do this in MCedit please?

Comment: @GoldNugget8 A bit late, but with MCEdit you can simply fly across the world without loading any new chunks. This is very helpful in narrowing down the place/direction of a specific location, because you can rule out the places you haven't been to. Basically, what Pronox commented on your question.